# ActionMailer Test, assert_equal from Rails guides documentation can never be true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, mailer

I'm going through the Rails 3 Guides, and looking at Testing Mailers section.

However, following those instructions, I wonder if they are buggy, and the assertion made can *never* be true.

#### This is the relevant section in the documentation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers

> 10.2.2 The Basic Test Case
>
> In this test, @expected is an instance of TMail::Mail that you can use
>   in your tests. It is defined in ActionMailer::TestCase. The test above
>   uses @expected to construct an email, which it then asserts with email
>   created by the custom mailer. The invite fixture is the body of the
>   email and is used as the sample content to assert against. The helper
>   read_fixture is used to read in the content from this file.

This is why I think it is the case:

test_card_update_notification(CardSenderMailerTest) [/Users/victorstan/Sites/ContactMonkey/test/unit/card_sender_mailer_test.rb:21]:

```
<"Date: Mon, 12 Mar 2012 22:54:38 -0400\r\nFrom: ContactMonkey <support@contactmonkey.com>\r\nTo: test@contactmonkey.com\r\nMessage-ID: <4f5eb6ee903b3_710a3fd4d6034ec8484b1@Victor-Stans-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>\r\nSubject: Bob Smith's ContactMonkey Card Has Been Updated!\r\nMime-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nHi Bob!\r\nYou asked to be notified when Bob Smith's card had been updated. You can view and download the new card by visiting their profile page:\r\n\r\nhttp://contactmonkey.com/bob\r\n\r\nUpdates at a glance:\r\n\r\n\tCard:\r\n\t\tTitle: Bauws\r\n\t\tOrganization: Fancy Org\r\n\t\tPersonal url: bob\r\n\r\n\tPhone:\r\n\t\tLabel: work\r\n\t\tNumber: 555 555 1234\r\n\r\n\tAddress:\r\n\t\tLabel: work\r\n\t\tStreet: 145 Dovercourt\r\n\t\tStreet2: \r\n\t\tCity: Toronto\r\n\t\tPostalcode: M6J3C5\r\n\t\tRegion: ON\r\n\t\tCountry: Canada\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nMake it a great day!\r\nContactMonkey\r\n\r\nProblems? Write to us at support@contactmonkey.com, or just reply to this message.\r\nhttp://contactmonkey.com\r\n"> expected but was
<"Date: Mon, 12 Mar 2012 22:54:38 -0400\r\nFrom: ContactMonkey <support@contactmonkey.com>\r\nTo: test@contactmonkey.com\r\nMessage-ID: <4f5eb6eeaeae1_710a3fd4d6034ec848559@Victor-Stans-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>\r\nSubject: Bob Smith's ContactMonkey Card Has Been Updated!\r\nMime-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nHi Bob!\r\nYou asked to be notified when Bob Smith's card had been updated. You can view and download the new card by visiting their profile page:\r\n\r\nhttp://contactmonkey.com/bob\r\n\r\nUpdates at a glance:\r\n\r\n\tCard:\r\n\t\tTitle: Bauws\r\n\t\tOrganization: Fancy Org\r\n\t\tPersonal url: bob\r\n\r\n\tPhone:\r\n\t\tLabel: work\r\n\t\tNumber: 555 555 1234\r\n\r\n\tAddress:\r\n\t\tLabel: work\r\n\t\tStreet: 145 Dovercourt\r\n\t\tStreet2: \r\n\t\tCity: Toronto\r\n\t\tPostalcode: M6J3C5\r\n\t\tRegion: ON\r\n\t\tCountry: Canada\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nMake it a great day!\r\nContactMonkey\r\n\r\nProblems? Write to us at support@contactmonkey.com, or just reply to this message.\r\nhttp://contactmonkey.com\r\n">.
```

Notice the difference?

```
Message-ID: <4f5eb6ee903b3_710a3fd4d6034ec8484b1@Victor-Stans-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
```

VS

```
Message-ID: <4f5eb6eeaeae1_710a3fd4d6034ec848559@Victor-Stans-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
```

How am I supposed to account for that? That's not part of my data, or my control as far as I know.

The assertion I am using:

```
assert_equal @expected.encoded, CardSenderMailer.card_update_notification(card, followers, field_updates).encoded
```

Which is very similar to the one used in the documentation:

```
assert_equal @expected.encoded, UserMailer.create_invite('me@example.com', 'friend@example.com', @expected.date).encoded
```

Comment: Can you post your mailer code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make the test pass with `.gsub(/Message-ID: <[\s\S]+>/, '')`

So that would make the assertion:

```
assert_equal @expected.encoded.gsub(/Message-ID: <[\s\S]+>/, ''), CardSender.card_update_notification(card, followers, field_updates).encoded.gsub(/Message-ID: <[\s\S]+>/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not pretty but I do something like the following:

```
test "able to mail something" do
    # bunch of @expected statements
    assert_equal encode(@expected), encode(MyMailer.mail(@user))
end  

def encode message
    message.encoded.gsub(/Message-ID: <.+>/, '').gsub(/Date: .+/, '')
end
```

If you want to share across mailer tests then modify `test_helper.rb` and add:

```
class ActionMailer::TestCase
    def encode message
        message.encoded.gsub(/Message-ID: <.+>/, '').gsub(/Date: .+/, '')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [mocha](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/) to stub 'has_message_id?' has similar results.  In my test, I add:

`Mail::Message.any_instance.stubs('has_message_id?').returns(true)`

Comment: I dropped this into a setup method on my mailer test suite, works flawlessly and doesn't need to be added to every test case.